# how to remove blank space let by the hidden parameter?

Tags: parameters, birt

I created a report with some hidden parameters.

When the box show up, I can see additional spaces because of the hidden parameters.

Is it possible to remove this extra spaces?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume these parameters are inside of or connected to a visual object like a text field. Anyways: You can try to **set a fixed width and height of 0px** for those elements.

Comment: Where can I add a width and height?

Comment: Usually, you find those attributes in the Properties-Tab under "General". See: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_birt_report_guide/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/eclipse_birt_report_format.7.12.html

Comment: this is for a table or a grid.
The parameter box has been created by BIRT, I didn't create it

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the problem?